# Rails and PHP encode64 not agreeing

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, sha1, hmac

I'm try to create an HMAC in Rails and verify it in PHP.
Rails shell:

```
       pry(main)>appsecret = '00916893840fe0a29dfdc261efd3a26a&'           
       pry(main)>OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha1', appsecret, 'GET&http%3A%2F%2Fopen.tianya.cn%2Foauth%2Frequest_token.php&oauth_consumer_key%3Dfc69b18eb12bab1e9b35d1093c4de9290516cfdc4%26oauth_nonce%3Dc09e4bf167fbc7eb374b1abb02b5268d%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1366882036%26oauth_version%3D1.0')
       => "8494f6237ee6042a3da8848db21284be17bf6ade"
```

PHP:

```
      $appsecret = '00916893840fe0a29dfdc261efd3a26a&';
      $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $appsecret, 'GET&http%3A%2F%2Fopen.tianya.cn%2Foauth%2Frequest_token.php&oauth_consumer_key%3Dfc69b18eb12bab1e9b35d1093c4de9290516cfdc4%26oauth_nonce%3Dc09e4bf167fbc7eb374b1abb02b5268d%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1366882036%26oauth_version%3D1.0',true));
      var_dump($signature);
```

Rails result:8494f6237ee6042a3da8848db21284be17bf6ade

PHP result:ayw4/L22fCtXPvPPGaY/Ud8yhMU=

Any help will be great appreciated!

Comment: On ruby on rails => `00916893840fe0a29dfdc261efd3a26a& = 8494f6237ee6042a3da8848db21284be17bf6ade`

On php =>  `00916893840fe0a29dfdc261efd3a26a& = ayw4/L22fCtXPvPPGaY/Ud8yhMU= ` ?

Comment: i think the order of parameters for hash_hmac is inverted in php, first data, then key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. Your ruby output is returned as ascii hex, not raw, and you are not base64 encoding it
2. You have the argument order for the PHP [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function wrong.

Ruby:

```
appsecret = '00916893840fe0a29dfdc261efd3a26a&'
data = 'GET&http%3A%2F%2Fopen.tianya.cn%2Foauth%2Frequest_token.php&oauth_consumer_key%3Dfc69b18eb12bab1e9b35d1093c4de9290516cfdc4%26oauth_nonce%3Dc09e4bf167fbc7eb374b1abb02b5268d%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1366882036%26oauth_version%3D1.0'

digest = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', appsecret, data)
Base64.encode64(digest)
```

PHP:

```
$appsecret = '00916893840fe0a29dfdc261efd3a26a&';
$data = 'GET&http%3A%2F%2Fopen.tianya.cn%2Foauth%2Frequest_token.php&oauth_consumer_key%3Dfc69b18eb12bab1e9b35d1093c4de9290516cfdc4%26oauth_nonce%3Dc09e4bf167fbc7eb374b1abb02b5268d%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1366882036%26oauth_version%3D1.0';

$digest = hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $appsecret, true);
echo base64_encode($digest);
```

Both produce `hJT2I37mBCo9qISNshKEvhe/at4=`. Note, however, that the ruby output also has a trailing new-line, so you will need to normalize this (either remove it in ruby or add one in PHP) if you want to compare them directly.

Comment: Thank you very much,your opinion is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different trial and error I found out how both the functionality were similar..this will give you the desired resut same as ruby:

```
$appsecret = '00916893840fe0a29dfdc261efd3a26a&';
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', 'GET&http%3A%2F%2Fopen.tianya.cn%2Foauth%2Frequest_token.php&oauth_consumer_key%3Dfc69b18eb12bab1e9b35d1093c4de9290516cfdc4%26oauth_nonce%3Dc09e4bf167fbc7eb374b1abb02b5268d%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1366882036%26oauth_version%3D1.0',$appsecret);
var_dump($signature);
```

Result:

```
string(40) "8494f6237ee6042a3da8848db21284be17bf6ade"
```

In PHP order of parameters for hash_hmac is inverted in php, first data, then key. 
the ruby output is not base64 encoded so you do not have to base64 encode in your PHP..